# PHP - For Loop incrementing

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, php-5.3

This might looks dumb, but I have no idea how $a += 3; works.
I can't figure out, for every answer I would be grateful

```
<?php
$a = 0;
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) { 
    $a += 3; // How this actually works
}
echo $a; // Echoing 15
?>
```

Comment: `+=` is an Assignment Operator ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)) in PHP.

Comment: it adds whatever is on the right, to the existing value of the $variable. in your case. $a gets increased by 3 with every loop.

Comment: Thank you. Gotcha